# Which Version should be use for Spark Cassandra Connector.?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am confused and want to know about which version I should use for spark-cassandra connector,Cassandra Driver and Scala version. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How about checking [README](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility)?

Comment: @zero323 Thanks for the reply. I actually wants the version combinations of spark and cassandra connector.

Comment: @UmairIqbal RTFM ! It's in the link provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

And to use spark with cassandra there is one good blog if u like to look into

https://blog.knoldus.com/2015/06/23/apache-spark-cassandra-basic-steps-to-install-and-configure-cassandra-and-use-it-with-apache-spark-with-example/